# prioritize LDAP when using passwd and group

Tags: linux, authentication, ldap, openldap

I have several servers, one of which, say S1, is used as LDAP server. Other servers are configured to authenticate against the LDAP server.

When a user is added, I always create a unix user on S1, then migrate it to LDAP, which I think is incorrect, but I don't know a better way. Now I want to change password for my LDAP user on S1, but `passwd` prompts `current (UNIX) password` instead of `current (LDAP) password`.

How do I give LDAP higher priority than local authentication for `passwd` and other situations like login?

Another question by the way is, can I use LDAP to specify UNIX group for users?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When a user is added, I always create a unix user on S1, then migrate it to LDAP, which I think is incorrect, but I don't know a better way.

You can directly integrate the NSS/PAM user management on your LDAP server with itself. I'm doing this with my [Æ-DIR](https://ae-dir.com) servers. Of course you have to be cautious to not lock out yourself if anything goes wrong. Thus it's a good idea to have, besides multiple replicas for fail-over, some sort of emergency login available.

> Now I want to change password for my LDAP user on S1, but passwd prompts current (UNIX) password instead of current (LDAP) password.

This is part of the local [PAM configuration](http://www.linux-pam.org/Linux-PAM-html/sag-configuration.html). You did not say anything about the Linux you're using. But today on most Linux variants PAM configuration is found in directory /etc/pam.d/. The relevant PAM config part is relevant PAM type when changing password is "password". Order can also be changed with PAM config.

BTW: I would not let all users login to the LDAP servers to change their password with `passwd` tool. I'd recommend to provide a web-based password self-service app for this use-case.

Be warned that PAM is complex: You can dig yourself large security holes and/or lock yourself out. So try first with throw-away virtual machines.

You also might want to tweak /etc/nsswitch.conf if you want to integrate your Linux with an LDAP-based user management.

You might want to look at full-blown ready-to-use solutions:

- [Centralised NSS backend for Linux](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/10508/centralised-nss-backend-for-linux/51157#51157)
- [Central user management with multiple servers with SSH keys, LDAP?](https://serverfault.com/questions/779332/how-to-only-allow-users-and-or-groups-access-certain-client-machines-that-are-co/922689#922689)